# can I instruct mariadb-install-db and mariadb to ignore 'user' setting in config?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.5

If I want to set up a mariadb a database and start mariadb as a local user:

I can easily override parameters such as `--datadir=$HOME/mariadb/data` or `--error_log=$HOME/mariadb/log/mysql_error.log`,
but I didn't find a straightforward way to have `mariadb-install-db` or `mysqld` to *ignore* the `user = mysql` setting that is set up in my system configuration files.

I'm running mariadb 10.5 on a ubuntu system, with standard system config files located in `/etc/mysql/`.

Note that this isn't really a blocking point, because I get *warnings* and both the install and the mysqld daemon apply their actions succesfully. It makes for scary warnings though:

```
$ mariadb-install-db --user=legec --datadir=$HOME/mariadb/data
chown: cannot access '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/auth_pam_tool_dir/auth_pam_tool': Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/auth_pam_tool_dir': Operation not permitted
2023-12-14 17:51:57 0 [Warning] Ignoring user change to 'legec' because the user was set to 'mysql' earlier on the command line
2023-12-14 17:51:57 0 [Warning] Ignoring user change to 'legec' because the user was set to 'mysql' earlier on the command line
...

Consider joining MariaDB's strong and vibrant community:
https://mariadb.org/get-involved/

$ echo $?
0
```

On my system, the `user = mysql` setting is provided in file `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`,
if I remove that line and remove the `--user=legec` option from cli, the warning goes away.

**Question**

Is there a way to instruct `mysqld` and `mariadb-install-db` to run as local user and completely ignore any `user` setting ?
or override an option to state "I want to run as current user, ignore any `user` setting" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straight forward way is to use `--no-defaults`.

```
mariadb-install-db --no-defaults  --datadir=$HOME/mariadb/data
```

With no `--user` setting it will use the current user as the installation user and not try to chown the auth_pam_tool helper.

`--no-defaults`, like all the `--default*` command line options must occur first in the command line.

---

To preserve existing settings:

```
my_print_defaults --mysqld | grep -Ev -- '--(user|datadir)' |
  xargs mariadb-install-db --no-defaults --datadir=$HOME/mariadb/data
```

Comment: you are right, I had actually tested that and it works. I was trying to find a way where I could keep the system defaults (`character_set_server`, `collation_server`, `provider_lz4` ...) and just override the storage location -- and the running user obviously ?

Comment: updated to include this functionality.